# Bash Script - not working as expected - Assistance required

Tags: bash, shell

Ive created a bash script with my very rookie knowledge which is 0, so its a script which is running on a pod, it curls a local endpoint and creates a metrics_file (containing a number of metrics). Then it greps the folder for a specific metric, if it finds the metric nothing is done, but if it cannot finds the metric or the file it will send an alert to a teams channel.

So its a Prometheus custom DeadManSwitch alert.
Right, so if I manually log into the pod shell as root, I trigger the script and it creates the metrics_file (I view the file and the metric is there and can be grepped manually) - but yet this script sends an alert to the teams channel, as if the grep part of it is not working as expected.

Here is the script (its in kubernetes configmap so yml)

```
`send_teams_deadman_alert_test.sh: >
    #!/bin/sh
    webhook_url="http://team-channel.url"
    channel="channel_name"
    message="No metrics received from Prometheus"
    metrics_file="/tmp/deadman.out"
    curl -v -f "http://localhost:7802/metrics" > "$metrics_file"
    if [ ! -s \"$metrics_file\" ] || ! grep -q
    prometheus_tsdb_head_min_time_seconds \"$metrics_file\"; then
       echo 1
       curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"channel\": \"$channel\", \"text\":       \"$message\"}" $webhook_url
      exit 1
   else
     echo 0
   fi
   rm -rf \"$metrics_file\"
```

`

Here is a debug of the triggered script:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying    127.0.0.1:7802...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 7802 (#0)
> GET /metrics HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:7802
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain; version=0.0.4; charset=utf-8
< Date: Fri, 10 Mar 2023 14:22:18 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
{ [3956 bytes data]
100  5806    0  5806    0     0  5669k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 
5669k
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

if [ ! -s \"$metrics_file\" ] || ! grep -q 
prometheus_tsdb_head_min_time_seconds \"$metrics_file\";    then
   echo 1
   curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"channel\": 
   \"$channel\", \"text\": \"$message\"}" $webhook_url
   exit 1
else
   echo 0

fi
+ '[' '!' -s '"/tmp/deadman.out"' ']'
+ echo 1
1
+ curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"channel": 
"channel_name", "text": "No metrics  received from Prometheus"}' 
http://team-channel.url
1+ exit 1
```

OH and 1 more thing - when the pod actually triggers the script via a telegraf plugin - it creates the metrics_file but its always empty. I think this is to do with securityContext: config on the pod. But first i think the manual trigger from root user should work as expected.

If anyone can come up with whatsup id appreciate some info. Thanks

Im expecting this script send and alert when the metric cannot be grepped!

Comment: To trigger the `curl`, you want the file to be not-empty AND to not have the grep in the file.  You use `||` which is an or.  Try `&&` for an and.

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` is not necessarily bash.  It is not unlikely to be bourne (predecessor to bash which is not syntax compatible)

Comment: @Nic3500 Hey Thanks for your response, so please excuse my scripting knowledge.  So im expecting to see the metric, as this tells me the application is running. So i need this script to trigger the curl when the metric is absent right. The grep is needed as the metrics_file would contain quite alot of different metrics. Unless there is a way to curl the localhost:7802/metrics for only that specific metric and push it to the metrics-file. Im not sure how to go about scripting it to not be empty and to trigger.

Comment: Unless this is some kubernetes/yml thing I'm not aware of, the double-quotes around `$metrics_file` should *not* be escaped -- it looks like those escapes are making it treat the double-quotes as literally part of the filename, which will cause problems.

Comment: @GordonDavisson indeed that is correct. I finally got something working, seems i had some missing "statements". For its working when manually triggering it from the pod as root user. I had some instances where it didnt find the metric, i think this is due to a timing issue when it curl the local endpoint and the local endpoint is at that time being updates which is every 60s (its gets overwritten with new metric data) but ill have to confirm. I think next its a case of get the pod to automatically execute the script with the correct permissions.